# How long does my MEGU pet have until it dies?

Tags: ios, kawaii-pet-megu

Megu pets can apparently "starve" or die or something now, they have a Health Meter which slowly falls and only refills when you feed them. When it runs out, they're supposed to die.

What's the longest period of time my Megu pet will survive without food, assuming he starts with a full Health bar? Does anything like level effect how quickly the bar drains?

Comment: What system is this game on? a smartphone?

Comment: @AshleyNunn it's an iPhone game